# PHP auto type casting while inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, casting

I am working on PHP API where I will pass few parameters along with data to insert that in database. that array will have string type of data always. I want to type cast this data automatically into the type of the corresponding column. I think it is not possible, using some inbuilt PHP functions. is there any workaround or a way to achieve it?

I am using MYSQL as DB and PHP latest version.

Comment: Just pass the strings. MySQL will automatically convert for you.

Comment: no need for casting. just tell PDO/mysqli that you're sending in strings when you bind your query's placeholder parameters.

Comment: How can I tell it to PDO?

Comment: do you want this for validation or for your own ease?

Comment: for my own ease..i need it.